# Auto-Implemented Property Classes as Parameter

Tags: c#, automatic-properties, method-parameters

I'd like to pass a property class reference into a method.
For example:

```
Class SQLiteTables
{
    public class tblPersonnel
    {
        public int PsnID { get; set; }
        public string PsnFirstName { get; set; }
        public string PsnMiddleName { get; set; }
        public string PsnLastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class tblSchedules
    {
        public int SchID { get; set; }
        public string SchDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime SchStartDtm { get; set; }
        public DateTime SchEndDtm { get; set; }

    ...

    public class TableName
    {
        public int Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }

        ...

        public string FieldN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would want to create a method something like this:

```
public void ThisMethod(PropertyClass propertyclassname)
{
        List<propertyclassname> TempList = dbConn.Table<propertyclassname>().ToList<propertyclassname>();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ThisMethod(tblPersonnel);
ThisMethod(tblSchedules);
```

I'm trying to avoid making multiple methods for each property. I want it to be one reusable method but I can't seem to figure out how. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do inside the `ThisMethod` method?

Comment: You can create your class through reflection and pass it to the method

Comment: Why do you have so many classes which all look the same other than the property names? It's hard to see what bigger problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you need a method which accepts class name as input parameter and set the properties of those class. If it is so, you can use Reflection Concept.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually the number of properties vary for each class.

Comment: So you haven't given a representative example, which doesn't help. And you still haven't explained what you're really trying to achieve. It's very hard to help you without more information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use generics:

```
public void ThisMethod<T>(T mySet) where T : MySetBaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

What do you whant to do in the method and who is calling it?

Answer (score 0):

what you  are trying  to accomplish is not so easy with your actual  logic  but if you  change it to the following may be you  solve it

```
public abstract class PropertySetBase
     {
           public  abstract int Property_int1 { get; set; }
        public abstract string Property1 { get; set; }
        public abstract string Property2 { get; set; }
        public  abstract  string Property3 { get; set; }
     }
```

first  class

```
    public class PropertySet1:PropertySetBase
    {

    public override int  Property_int1
{
      get 
    { 

    }
      set 
    { 
    }
}

public override string  Property1
{
      get 
    { 
    }
      set 
    { 

    }
}

public override string  Property2
{
      get 
    { 
    }
      set 
    { 
    }
}

public override string  Property3
{
      get 
    {   
    }
      set 
    { 
    }
}
}
```

second class

```
    public class PropertySet2:PropertySetBase
    {

public override int  Property_int1
{
      get 
    { 
    }
      set 
    { 
    }
}

public override string  Property1
{
      get 
    { 
    }
      set 
    { 
    }
}

public override string  Property2
{
      get 
    { 
    }
      set 
    { 
    }
}

public override string  Property3
{
      get 
    { 

    }
      set 
    { 

    }
}
}
```

and here  how your method should written  to accept any  propertiesclass

```
public void ThisMethod( PropertySetBase propertyclassname)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to repeatedly use propertyset type and for that you can use IEnumerable

```
public class PropertySet
{
        public int Property0 { get; set; }
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

use list of this type in your method for as many item you want to use in your method

```
public void ThisMethod(List<PropertySet> propertyclass)
{

}
```